# does opensea treats differently ERC721 and ERC721URIStorage? What about using pinata vs custom IPFS server?

Tags: polygon, ipfs, opensea, meta-data

I developed a contract and uploaded it to the polygon chain. I wanted to use my own IPFS node to be as "decentralized as possible", so I used URIStorage. It costs more gas but because in polygon is cheaper it still comes out at a reasonable price. My problem is that initially I uploaded the whole contract pointing to the same gif (a sort of coming soon) but when changing the metadata for the real thing, opensea fails to update, even though I can see the changes on polygonscan and I can access those URIs.

I am wondering now if this way of doing things if inefficient from OpenSea's part. Maybe I am missing to emit an event, or maybe if metadata and images where at pinata Opensea would update them quicker?

Thanks for any advice